# My schema.ini file is being ignored when using DoCmd.TransferText() from .Net

Tags: ms-access, vba, schema, office-interop

My schema.ini file is being ignored.I get the same results whether I have a scheme.ini file in the same folder as my tab file or not. All of the columns end up in a single column. I am trying to use a schema.ini as I am importing tab delimited files. The results make perfect sense if it is trying to import a comma delim file.

So my postulate is that the schema.ini file is just being ignored.

I am running Access from a .Net program using Microsoft Access 14.0 Object.Library.

I am using this command from .net:

```
Access.DoCmd.TransferText( Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.AcTextTransferType.acImportDelim, , TableName, TabFile, HasFieldNames)
```

Here is my schema.ini file, not that it matters since it is being completely ignored:

```
[impacts.txt]
Format=TabDelimited
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=0
```

Clues? Thanks!

EDIT:
I tried running this from within an Access Module with the same results.

I tried editing the registry to change the Format value there. Same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an action query, either append or make-table, as the use of `schema.ini` files can work directly in an Access query of a text file. Below assumes .ini file is in same directory as text file.

```sql
INSERT INTO mytableName
SELECT * FROM [text;Database=C:\Path\To\Text\File].[impacts.txt]

SELECT * INTO newtableName FROM [text;Database=C:\Path\To\Text\File].[impacts.txt]
```

Comment: You are a genius! Only nitpick is your version requires that the table already exist in Access. Edit your answer to add `Select * INTO impacts from (SELECT * FROM [text;Database=D:\EnvironProcessing\Q3_2017\WI\brrts].[impacts.txt])` and I will mark you as the answer.

Comment: @BradMathews ... the query can work with either append or make-table query...just like `DoCmd.TransferText` can!

Comment: Yes, I understood that, sorry my lack of clarity.

Comment: Over at my [MSDN post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/00a1b60a-4e8b-4110-9f0e-cf0a54a9bcfd/my-schemaini-file-is-being-ignored-when-using-docmdtransfertext-from-net?forum=accessdev) I received a reply that combines Parfait's solution with ADO.Net so I do not need to use Access Automation and its overhead.

Comment: And I agree. This solution is a pure SQL call (nothing to do with Access.exe which `DoCmd.TransferText` is part of), exactly as MSN post shows. The intention was for you to place this query in the general purpose language you use -VB, C#, heck even Python, R, PHP! Remember SQL is a special-purpose language.